# Using Arquillian and glassfish embedded container in websphere environment

Tags: java, glassfish, jboss-arquillian

I was able to successfully create a Arquillian + Glassfish embedded and Arquillian + websphere embedded POC project. Now I'm trying to integrate Arquillian with my actual development project. Below is the breif information about my project.

```
IDE: IBM RAD 8.5.X
Server: IBM Websphere 8.5.X
Development: EJB3.1 complaint code (lot of EJBS)
UNIT Testing: JUnit4.11, Mockito etc.,
EJB Unit (or Integration) Testing: None, trying to use Arquillian 1.1.4
Deployment: using IDE RAD deployment
```

At present my project have neither ant nor maven script to create ear and deploy on server. We are heavily depended on IBM RAD to deploy our application in development mode. Hence the project is using Websphere JDK and Websphere runtime environment (in .classpath).

I'm trying to develop unit test cases for EJB with Arquillian + Glassfish embedded container. I can't use websphere embedded container as we have many @Remote ejb's and websphere embedded container doesn't support @Remote support. At this time I don't want to remove the websphere run time dependencies from classpath as I need to analyze the impact and convince my inhouse architectures.

**Is it possible to use Arquillian + Glassfish embedded container along with Websphere runtime.** I tried to pass JVM properties to look for glassfish embedded EJB Provider but it's still trying to load websphere container. Of course, it is because Websphere runtime library is available through .claspath.

Any comments or help is really appreciable.

**Test Case**

```
 @RunWith(Arquillian.class)
    public class CalculatorBeanTest {


        @Deployment

        public static JavaArchive createDeployment() {
            return ShrinkWrap.create(JavaArchive.class, "test.jar")
                            .addPackage(CalculatorBean.class.getPackage())
                            .addAsManifestResource(EmptyAsset.INSTANCE, "beans.xml");
        }

        @EJB
        private Calculator calc;


        @Test
        public void testAddition() {
            assertThat(calc, notNullValue());
            double result = calc.plus(10d, 5d);
            assertThat(result, equalTo(15d));
        }
    }
```

**arquillian.xml**

```
<arquillian xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian/arquillian_1_0.xsd"
    xmlns:gfembed="urn:arq:org.jboss.arquillian.container.glassfish.embedded_3">

    <container qualifier="glassfish-embedded" default="true">
         <configuration>
             <property name="resourcesXml">test-resources/glassfish-resources.xml</property>
         </configuration>
    </container>

</arquillian>
```

**glassfish-resources.xml**

```
<!DOCTYPE resources PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Application Server 9.0 Resource Definitions //EN"
   "http://www.sun.com/software/appserver/dtds/sun-resources_1_4.dtd">
<resources>
```

**RAD classpath**

```
<classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jst.server.core.container/com.ibm.ws.ast.st.runtime.runtimeTarget.v85/WebSphere Application Server v8.5">
    <attributes>
        <attribute name="owner.project.facets" value="wcg"/>
    </attributes>
</classpathentry>
<classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/WebSphere Application Server V8.5 JRE">
    <attributes>
        <attribute name="owner.project.facets" value="java"/>
    </attributes>
</classpathentry>

<classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/test-scope/glassfish-embedded-all-3.1.2.2.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/test-scope/arquillian-config-api-1.1.4.Final.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/test-scope/arquillian-config-impl-base-1.1.4.Final.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/test-scope/arquillian-container-impl-base-1.1.4.Final.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/test-scope/arquillian-container-spi-1.1.4.Final.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/test-scope/arquillian-container-test-api-1.1.4.Final.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/test-scope/arquillian-container-test-impl-base-1.1.4.Final.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/test-scope/arquillian-container-test-spi-1.1.4.Final.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/test-scope/arquillian-core-api-1.1.4.Final.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/test-scope/arquillian-core-impl-base-1.1.4.Final.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/test-scope/arquillian-core-spi-1.1.4.Final.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/test-scope/arquillian-glassfish-embedded-3.1-1.0.0.CR4.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/test-scope/arquillian-junit-container-1.1.4.Final.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/test-scope/arquillian-junit-core-1.1.4.Final.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/test-scope/arquillian-persistence-api-1.0.0.Alpha7.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/test-scope/arquillian-persistence-core-1.0.0.Alpha7.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/test-scope/arquillian-persistence-dbunit-1.0.0.Alpha7.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/test-scope/arquillian-persistence-spi-1.0.0.Alpha7.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/test-scope/arquillian-protocol-servlet-1.1.4.Final.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/test-scope/arquillian-test-api-1.1.4.Final.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/test-scope/arquillian-test-impl-base-1.1.4.Final.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/test-scope/arquillian-test-spi-1.1.4.Final.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/test-scope/arquillian-testenricher-cdi-1.1.4.Final.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/test-scope/arquillian-testenricher-ejb-1.1.4.Final.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/test-scope/arquillian-testenricher-initialcontext-1.1.4.Final.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/test-scope/arquillian-testenricher-resource-1.1.4.Final.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/test-scope/arquillian-transaction-api-1.0.1.Final.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/test-scope/arquillian-transaction-impl-base-1.0.1.Final.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/test-scope/arquillian-transaction-jta-1.0.1.Final.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/test-scope/arquillian-transaction-spi-1.0.1.Final.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/test-scope/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/test-scope/commons-logging-1.1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/test-scope/dbunit-2.5.0.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/test-scope/fest-assert-1.4.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/test-scope/fest-util-1.1.6.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/test-scope/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/test-scope/hamcrest-library-1.3.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/test-scope/jackson-core-asl-1.9.2.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/test-scope/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.2.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/test-scope/junit-4.11.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/test-scope/log4j-1.2.13.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/test-scope/mockito-all-1.9.5.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/test-scope/poi-3.2-FINAL.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/test-scope/shrinkwrap-api-1.2.2.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/test-scope/shrinkwrap-descriptors-api-base-2.0.0-alpha-5.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/test-scope/shrinkwrap-descriptors-spi-2.0.0-alpha-5.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/test-scope/shrinkwrap-impl-base-1.2.2.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/test-scope/shrinkwrap-spi-1.2.2.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/test-scope/slf4j-api-1.7.2.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/test-scope/snakeyaml-1.10.jar"/>
```

**Exception**

Apr 3, 2015 6:50:49 PM com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.CommonClassLoaderServiceImpl findDerbyClient
INFO: Cannot find javadb client jar file, derby jdbc driver will not be available by default.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.ibm.ejs.ras.hpel.HpelHelper
    at com.ibm.ejs.ras.RasHelper.getThreadId(RasHelper.java:1764)
    at com.ibm.ejs.ras.RasEvent6$1.initialValue(RasEvent6.java:101)
    at java.lang.ThreadLocal.setInitialValue(ThreadLocal.java:152)
    at java.lang.ThreadLocal.get(ThreadLocal.java:142)
    at com.ibm.ejs.ras.RasEvent6.<init>(RasEvent6.java:292)
    at com.ibm.ejs.ras.MessageEvent6.<init>(MessageEvent6.java:203)
    at com.ibm.ejs.ras.Tr.fireMessageEvent(Tr.java:1562)
    at com.ibm.ejs.ras.Tr.error(Tr.java:730)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.java.javaURLContextFactory.isNameSpaceAccessable(javaURLContextFactory.java:108)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.urlbase.UrlContextFactory.getObjectInstance(UrlContextFactory.java:85)
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getURLContext(NamingManager.java:706)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getURLOrDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:422)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getURLOrDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:376)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.rebind(InitialContext.java:448)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.publishObject(GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.java:206)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.publishObject(GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.java:189)
    at org.glassfish.kernel.javaee.MEJBService.postConstruct(MEJBService.java:81)
    at com.sun.hk2.component.AbstractCreatorImpl.inject(AbstractCreatorImpl.java:131)
    at com.sun.hk2.component.ConstructorCreator.initialize(ConstructorCreator.java:91)
    at com.sun.hk2.component.AbstractCreatorImpl.get(AbstractCreatorImpl.java:82)
    at com.sun.hk2.component.SingletonInhabitant.get(SingletonInhabitant.java:67)
    at com.sun.hk2.component.EventPublishingInhabitant.get(EventPublishingInhabitant.java:139)
    at com.sun.hk2.component.AbstractInhabitantImpl.get(AbstractInhabitantImpl.java:78)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.AppServerStartup.run(AppServerStartup.java:229)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.AppServerStartup.doStart(AppServerStartup.java:145)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.AppServerStartup.start(AppServerStartup.java:136)
    at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.GlassFishImpl.start(GlassFishImpl.java:79)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.glassfish.embedded_3_1.GlassFishContainer.start(GlassFishContainer.java:174)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.ContainerImpl.start(ContainerImpl.java:199)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerLifecycleController$8.perform(ContainerLifecycleController.java:163)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerLifecycleController$8.perform(ContainerLifecycleController.java:157)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerLifecycleController.forContainer(ContainerLifecycleController.java:255)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerLifecycleController.startContainer(ContainerLifecycleController.java:156)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:99)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:81)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.ContainerDeploymentContextHandler.createContainerContext(ContainerDeploymentContextHandler.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:145)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:116)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventImpl.fire(EventImpl.java:67)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerLifecycleController$2.perform(ContainerLifecycleController.java:77)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerLifecycleController$2.perform(ContainerLifecycleController.java:70)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerLifecycleController.forEachSuiteContainer(ContainerLifecycleController.java:221)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerLifecycleController.startSuiteContainers(ContainerLifecycleController.java:69)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:99)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:81)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:145)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:116)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventImpl.fire(EventImpl.java:67)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.client.ContainerEventController.execute(ContainerEventController.java:86)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:99)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:81)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createSuiteContext(TestContextHandler.java:65)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:145)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:116)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.EventTestRunnerAdaptor.beforeSuite(EventTestRunnerAdaptor.java:68)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.run(Arquillian.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ibm.ejs.ras.hpel.HpelHelper
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:434)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassHelper(ClassLoader.java:688)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:667)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:358)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:650)
    ... 89 more
```